# Is there any way I can add elements to list like shown?

Tags: c++, list, vector, graph

I'm trying to add an element to a list in a vector. The error occurs in addEdge method because it can't access the wanted container (Segmentation fault). the graph is a vector where each container contains a list of the vertices connected to it(and weight of that edge, which in this case is 0).

```
Graph(int n, bool directed)
    {
        this->n = n;
        graph.reserve(n);
        this->directed = directed;
        this->m = 0;
    }

    void addEdge(int x, int y)
    {
        graph[x - 1].push_back({y - 1, 0});
        if (!directed)
            graph[y - 1].push_back({x - 1, 0});
        m++;
    }
```

M is a number of edges and n is the number of vertices. I`ve done this many times before with simple arrays, but haven't tried it yet with vectors.
The class consists of:

```
int n;
int m;
bool directed;
std::vector<std::list<std::pair<int, int>>> graph;
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do... Do you want to add an item to a list in the graph or add a list to the graph?

Comment: I don't get your container format for the graph. Why the `std::list`? Why don't you just use a `std::map<std::pair, Edge>` where `Edge` is a type with further information (if required).

Comment: You definitely have a typo in the first method (the constructor). What is `graph` alone on a line? Also, I don't understand what you're trying to do and why you've shown us these two methods/functions.

Comment: Is that a better solution? I know I`m taking more memory, but what is the time complexity of a search in the map? Is it log n?

Comment: @Vojin we still don't know what you're trying to do. Your container for the graph doesn't look like it represents a simple graph. Please add more information to your question. And yes `std::map` is O(log n). `std::unordered_map` is O(1).

Comment: Sorry for bad English, hope that explanation helps a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `graph.reserve(n)`, `graph.size()` is still zero. `reserve` affects the capacity of the vector, not its size. Then `graph[x - 1]` exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an index out of bounds (any value of `x` produces an index out of bounds, since the vector is empty).

You probably meant `graph.resize(n)`